# Text in UIPrintInteractionController is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I want to print some PDF NSData, and when I present `UIPrintInteractionController` PDF presents correctly, but text and other data on `UITableViewCell`'s of `UIPrintInteractionController` not visible.

Image:
[image]

Code:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

printController.delegate = self;

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = [self.pdfURL lastPathComponent];
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
printController.printInfo = printInfo;
printController.showsPageRange = YES;
printController.printingItem = self.pdfData;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %lu", error.domain, (long)error.code);
    }
};

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [printController presentFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:true completionHandler:completionHandler];
} else {
    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

What can cause such problem and how to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

After ignoring this issue, I found that any subclass of `UITableViewCell` in my app has `textLabel.textColor` set by default to white color. And I can't change it programmatically or in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have category of `UITableViewCell` which overrides `layoutSubviews` method like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // some configurations
}
```

After removing this method, everything works fine.